# python socket listen for incoming netcat send to mysql

Tags: python, sockets

I have a remote server which sends it's hostname, ip and time every 5 minutes via netcat:

```
/bin/echo 'host433 192.168.1.1 2017-09-20-21:55:31'|/usr/bin/nc 192.50.38.188 10000
```

My listening server receives it just fine with a:

```
nc -lk 10000 
host433 192.168.1.1 2017-09-20-21:55:31
```

I'm working on a python script which will do what the nc -l does but takes the incoming data and write it to a database.  This is what I have thus far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,socket
import MySQLdb as dbi

con = dbi.connect("localhost","root","password","hostips")
cur = con.cursor()
s = socket.socket()
port = 10000
s.bind(('', port))
s.listen(5)

while True:
   # Establish connection with client.
   c, addr = s.accept()
   clean =  addr[0]

   SQL = ("INSERT INTO hostips(ID, IP, Time)"
         " VALUES('hostname', 'ip', 'timestamp')")

   try:
      cur.execute(SQL)
      con.commit()
   except dbi.Error,e:
      sys.stderr.write("SQL failed: "+SQL+"\n")

   sys.stdout.flush()
   c.close()
```

My question is how do I parse the incoming data and set them as variable for hostname, ip and timestamp to write to my database?

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Read a line from the socket, use `split()` to separate the values, then substitute that list into the cursor.

Comment: @Barmar I got it to split the line:  ['0000', '192.168.1.1', '2017-09-20-21:55:31'].  How do I go about setting ID=0000, IP=192.168.1.1. Date=2017...?

Comment: Read any tutorial on prepared statements in Python SQL.